# ZF2 - Using zfc-rbac for custom route redirection

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using ZfcRbac and need to add a custom re-direct strategy. I have read the document here [re-direct strategy documents](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/blob/master/docs/05.%20Strategies.md#redirectstrategy) but am not 100% sure how to implement an alternative stratergy for my use case:

1. When a user attempts to enter a route in an admin area I currently redirect back to the admin login page if they are not already logged in.
2. When a customer logs into their account pages, I need to re-direct them to the customer login pages. Currently they are re-directed to the admin login pages.

My Module.php file has this::

```
    public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
{
    $t = $e->getTarget();
    $t->getEventManager()->attach(
        $t->getServiceManager()->get('ZfcRbac\View\Strategy\RedirectStrategy')
    );
}
```

My Global has this::

```
<?php
return [
'zfc_rbac' => [
    'protection_policy' => \ZfcRbac\Guard\GuardInterface::POLICY_ALLOW,
    'guards'            => [
        'ZfcRbac\Guard\RouteGuard' => [
            //ADMIN ACCOUNT GUARDS
            'user'                 => ['admin-master'],
            'user/login'           => ['guest'],
            'user/logout'          => ['admin-master', 'merchant-worker', 'guest'],
            'user/register'        => ['admin-master', 'merchant-admin', 'guest'],
            'user/change-password' => ['admin-master', 'merchant-worker'],
            'user/forgot-password' => ['guest'],
            //CUSTOMER ACCOUNT GUARDS
            'customer'             => ['customer'],
        ]
    ],
    'identity_provider' => \RoleBasedUser\Service\AuthenticationService::class,
    'role_provider'     => [
        'ZfcRbac\Role\ObjectRepositoryRoleProvider' => [
            'object_manager'     => 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default',
            'class_name'         => 'RoleBasedUser\Entity\HierarchicalRole',
            'role_name_property' => 'name'
        ]
    ],
    'redirect_strategy' => [
        'redirect_when_connected'        => true,
        'redirect_to_route_connected'    => 'home',
        'redirect_to_route_disconnected' => 'user/login',
        'append_previous_uri'            => true,
        'previous_uri_query_key'         => 'redirectTo'
    ],
]
];
```

To make this work, I believe I need to write a custom stratergy, however I am not 100% certain how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually quite easy to solve once I got my head around ZfcRbac. What I did was to create my own RedirectStrategy:: MyRedirectStrategy and to update the config global.

config global: An array of routes and the route to direct to. This could have been made more extensive to include a variety of routes and redirects but I only needed one additional one.

```
       'redirect_to_route_disconnected' => [
        'routes' => [
            'user','other1','other2'
        ],
        'redirect' => 'user/login'
    ],
    'redirect_to_route_connected' => [
        'routes' => [
            'user','other1','other2'
        ],
        'redirect' => 'user'
    ],
```

Default settings are for Customer pages and the alternative pages are for my admin.

I added the following check to my extended strategy:

```
 if ($event->getRouteMatch()) {
        $routeMatch = $event->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
        $redirect_to_route_disconnected  =  $this->sl->get('config')['zfc_rbac']['redirect_to_route_disconnected'];
        $redirect_to_route_connected     =  $this->sl->get('config')['zfc_rbac']['redirect_to_route_connected'];
    }  else {
        $routeMatch = '';
        $redirect_to_route_disconnected = array();
        $redirect_to_route_connected = array();

    }
```

And then added a check and set:

```
if ($this->authenticationService->hasIdentity()) {
        if (!$this->options->getRedirectWhenConnected()) {
            return;
        }
        if (in_array($routeMatch,$redirect_to_route_connected['routes'])) {
            $this->options->setRedirectToRouteConnected($redirect_to_route_connected['redirect']);
        }
        $redirectRoute = $this->options->getRedirectToRouteConnected();
    } else {
          if (in_array($routeMatch,$redirect_to_route_disconnected['routes'])) {
            $this->options->setRedirectToRouteDisconnected($redirect_to_route_disconnected['redirect']);
        }
        $redirectRoute = $this->options->getRedirectToRouteDisconnected();
    }
```

I chose to set the customer pages as the default as I have no problem with an admin being directed to the customer pages due to a missed route check.The other way round would serve to confuse the customers.